# How to decode a exif UserComment?

Tags: image-processing, decode, exif

I have some important metadata information in the UserComment field of the EXIF header of a PNG image. I am trying to retrieve a readable text, but I don't know what is the current encoding.

```
<exif:UserComment>
<rdf:Alt>
 <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">    FM0   FC000000000:zzzzzz1 f144 078043881a29e1e816c14c0 bac 87152  a9   012c  a3   0106  a8   0 e0  b1   0 ba  bc   0 94  d1   0 6e 102   0 48 155   0 22 1af   0 36 12f   0 3f 13f   0 48 19f   0 51 1b6   0 48 18d   0 48 18d   0..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................</rdf:li>
</rdf:Alt> 
</exif:UserComment>
```

Comment: Did you find anything? My quick search led to this: *According to JEITA CP-3451, UserComment is rather special thing with a hairy character encoding hack in the first 8 bytes. It might be intended to hold a less restricted copy of ImageDescription: "A tag for Exif users to write keywords or comments on the image besides those in ImageDescription, and without the character code limitations of the ImageDescription tag.*. That said, the use of RDF/XML tags would suggest that the field was written by some software dealing with structured data... Where did the PNG come from? What kind of device?